# Postgres query to get data datewise

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I am using PostgreSQL.
I have a table like below:

```
ID   product_id   Date         Qty
-----------------------------------
1    12           2008-06-02   50
2     3           2008-07-12    5
3    12           2009-02-10   25
4    10           2012-11-01   22
5     2           2011-03-25    7
```

Now I want the result like below (i.e product wise sum of qty field of last 4 years):

```
product_id
QTY(current_year)  
QTY( current year + last_year)  
QTY_last2_years 
QTY > 2 years
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id
      ,sum(CASE mydate >=  x.t THEN qty END) AS qty_current_year
      ,sum(CASE mydate >= (x.t - interval '1 y') THEN qty END) AS qty_since_last_year
      ,sum(CASE mydate >= (x.t - interval '2 y')
            AND mydate <   x.t THEN qty END) AS qty_last_2_year
      ,sum(CASE mydate <  (x.t - interval '2 y') THEN qty END) AS qty_older
FROM   tbl
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT date_trunc('year', now()) AS t) x -- calculate once
GROUP  BY 1;
```

To resuse the calculated beginning of the current year I `CROSS JOIN` it as subquery `x`.